# include an editable textfield in a visualforce email template

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, pdf

I've got a visualforce email template that sends invoices attached in PDF. In the PDF there has to be a blank textfield that users can edit to add comments to the invoice. So the attached PDF needs to be editable. Does anyone know how to do this? I've been searching all over but I can't seem to find an answer.

I've tried adding apex form elements to the PDF but this is not supported in email.

Answer (score 2):

The Visualforce PDF renderer doesn't support PDF forms as far as I'm aware, so you'd need to use a third party tool such as acrobat to create these.  You'd also need a mechanism for the users to return you the updated document, PDFs are standalone when generated and not attached to a server-side controller.

You'll probably have more success sending them a link to a form on a Force.com site or similar, capturing their input through a regular VF form and then sending them the updated PDF  including their input.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I do not require to capture the input within salesforce. The receipts will be sent to the person handling the account. They will edit the invoice and send it to the client manually from there. 

I know how to create a PDF form with acrobat, but how would I include it in the generated invoice?

Comment: You'd have to upload it as a document/attachment and add that to the email programmatically I think - there's an example of this at: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_email_sending_attachments.htm